# Calculating this integral without trigonometric functions

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I have a problem with this integral and all the online calculators use t=atan(a). Is there a different way without using trigonometry?

$\int\frac{r^2}{(r^2+a^2)^\frac{5}{2}}dr$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the optimal substitution is:

$$
t = \arctan(r/a)
\quad \quad \Rightarrow \quad \quad
r = a\tan(t)
\quad \quad \Rightarrow \quad \quad
\text{d}r = \frac{a}{\cos^2(t)}\,\text{d}t
$$

from which:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{r^2}{\sqrt{\left(r^2+a^2\right)^5}}\,\text{d}r
& = \int \frac{\sin^2(t)}{a^2}\left(\cos(t)\,\text{d}t\right) \\
& = \frac{\sin^3(t)}{3\,a^2} + c \\
& = \frac{\left(\frac{r/a}{\sqrt{1+(r/a)^2}}\right)^3}{3\,a^2} + c \\
& = \frac{r^3}{3\,a^2\sqrt{\left(r^2+a^2\right)^3}} + c\,.
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Otherwise, with reference to [Euler substitutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution):

$$
t = r + \sqrt{r^2+a^2}
\quad \quad \Rightarrow \quad \quad
r = \frac{t^2-a^2}{2\,t}
\quad \quad \Rightarrow \quad \quad
\text{d}r = \frac{t^2+a^2}{2\,t^2}\,\text{d}t
$$

we get:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{r^2}{\sqrt{\left(r^2+a^2\right)^5}}\,\text{d}r 
& = \int \frac{4\,t\left(t^2-a^2\right)^2}{\left(t^2+a^2\right)^4}\,\text{d}t \\
& = \int \frac{4\,t}{\left(t^2+a^2\right)^2}\,\text{d}t - \int \frac{16\,a^2\,t}{\left(t^2+a^2\right)^3}\,\text{d}t + \int \frac{16\,a^4\,t}{\left(t^2+a^2\right)^4}\,\text{d}t \\
& = -\frac{2}{t^2+a^2} + \frac{4\,a^2}{\left(t^2+a^2\right)^2} - \frac{8\,a^4}{3\left(t^2+a^2\right)^3} + k \\
& = - \frac{2\left(3\,t^4+a^4\right)}{3\left(t^2+a^2\right)^3} + k \\
& = \frac{r^3}{3\,a^2\sqrt{\left(r^2+a^2\right)^3}} - \frac{1}{3\,a^2} + k \\
& = \frac{r^3}{3\,a^2\sqrt{\left(r^2+a^2\right)^3}} + c\,. \\
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Otherwise, with reference to [Rubi Rule 270](https://rulebasedintegration.org/integrationRules.html):

$$
\int (c\,x)^m\left(a + b\,x^n\right)^p\,\text{d}x = \frac{(c\,x)^{m+1}(a+b\,x^n)^{p+1}}{a\,c\,(m+1)} + k
$$

provided that $a\,c\,(m+1) \ne 0$ and $\frac{m+1}{n}+p+1 = 0$.